# MySQL reset variable after every row

Tags: mysql

I am running following query to get rank of business in all categories in terms of total number of likes.

```
SET @rownum = 0;
    SELECT b.*
    , (
    SELECT f4.rank from business as b2 INNER JOIN (
    select count(*) count,  @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as rank, f3.* from favourites as f3 GROUP BY f3.business_id ORDER BY count DESC ) as f4 ON b2.id = f4.business_id WHERE b2.id = 8 && f4.category_id=c.id
    )  
    as rank FROM business as b, category c where b.id=8
```

rank give NULL after first row, what should I do to reset @rownum to 0 for next row?

Comment: it is inner query within subquery

Comment: You mean @rownum is NULL and you want it to be 0 instead?

Comment: I want $rownum to get 0 and get increment for every other row from start.

Comment: Sorry, I think I still don't get what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have to somehow reset the @rownum to 0 after most inner query have returned result where it is currently getting incremented.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your code should increment @rownum for every row in the result because the first subquery and therefore the joined subquery should be executed once for every row.

In my opinion, your query is equivalent to the following:

```
 SELECT b.*, @rownum:=@rownum + 1 AS rank
 FROM business AS b, category c 
 WHERE b.id=8
```

---

*Edit:* If the problem is that you need to reset `@rownum` in a subquery but you're limited to a single column in the result, use something like this construct:

```
SELECT IF(@rownum:=0, NULL, f4.rank) AS rank FROM ...
```

The condition `@rownum:=0` is always evaluated, resetting `rownum`, and because it evaluates to 0, value of `f4.rank` is always returned.

Comment: query is even more complex, I have to somehow reset the $rownum after most inner query have returned result where it is currently getting incremented.

Comment: Whenever you need to reset `@rownum`, just use `@rownum:=0`. What is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: subquery 'SELECT f4.rank from business as b2' can only return 1 column, here I need to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the `@rownum` user variable, you could try including an inline view (i.e. a derived table) in the FROM clause.

It looks like you would need that within the inner correlated subquery. That correlated subquery should get re-executed for every row from `category c`, or at least every distinct value of c.id. (I'm going to assume that the `id` column in each table is the primary key.)

e.g.

```
    FROM ...
    JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
   WHERE ...
```

BUT... I am hesitant to recommend this approach to you, because I am having difficulty unwinding your SQL statement. It's not clear what resultset you want returned. It looks like that query should be throwing an exception, if that subquery returns more than one row. I just don't see anything explicit or implied that would give you that guarantee.

An example of the desired output would go a long ways to getting some useful help.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you want [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), [RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) or [DENSE_RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) partitioned by business_ID but I cannot penetrate your SQL

Some inputs & outputs would be helpful.

```
select * from
business as f4 inner join
(
select business_id, count(*),rank() over (partition by business_id order by count desc ) as rank) as counts
on f4.business_id=counts.business_id
```

might be close